# Compute a multiple integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume that we have a function $F(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_i - x_j)^2$. Is there a way (or existing result) to compute 
$$\int_0^1 \dots  \int_0^1 F(x_1, \dots, x_n) dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_n?$$ Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_integral

Comment: I see, thank you!